# What is the // directory on OS X

Tags: macos, unix

I accidently types **cd //** and was surprised to see OS X take me to a directory called *//*. It appears to be the root directory, but I am wondering why the **cd //** command did not throw an error.

Does **//** have any special meaning?

```
Seans-MacBook-Pro:/ sean$ cd //
Seans-MacBook-Pro:// sean$ pwd
//
Seans-MacBook-Pro:// sean$ ls
Applications            archive             net
Incompatible Software       bin             opt
Library             cores               private
Network             dev             sbin
System              etc             tmp
User Guides And Information home                usr
Users               mach_kernel         var
Volumes             mds
Seans-MacBook-Pro:// sean$ cd /
Seans-MacBook-Pro:/ sean$ ls
Applications            archive             net
Incompatible Software       bin             opt
Library             cores               private
Network             dev             sbin
System              etc             tmp
User Guides And Information home                usr
Users               mach_kernel         var
Volumes             mds
```

**EDIT**

I also noticed that **cd ///**, **cd ////** etc all resolve to root, and do not give an error. Only **cd //** is registered as being in the **//** directory.

```
Seans-MacBook-Pro:~ sean$ cd ///
Seans-MacBook-Pro:/ sean$ cd //
Seans-MacBook-Pro:// sean$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/` character is used as a separator, and - generally - any number of them can be collapsed into a single one. (This happens at the shell level, so when `bash` is parsing your input, for example)

This is also another way to write `/Users/Sean/` -  `////Users////Sean//`. However, the "//" is slightly special in some cases. You're still at the root (`/`) but `bash` does not collapse it immediately.

For more information, see this SuperUser post:
https://superuser.com/questions/389338/which-directory-does-path-represent-in-linux

Comment: Thank you Adam. I've added some text to my question.